# Getting Codenameone to respect the proxy settings on a windows desktop build

Tags: codenameone

We've built a codename one app, to be deployed primarily on a windows 8.1 system. The app works well, but we're having an issue getting the app to respect the defined system proxies, all requests are just done directly.

I've read this: https://www.codenameone.com/debugging-webservice-calls.html, but nothing there helps.

If we could pass in VM environment variable, then maybe java.net.useSystemProxies would solve our problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good idea, I've [added an issue for it](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1740) although I don't know if it will make it in time for 3.4 as this should be done carefully...